# How to make a profitable fast food shop?

Tags: biz-builder-delux

In Biz Builder Delux, I started with a game shop, with the manager from the first rival I have beaten I tried to open a fast food shop.

Cannot seem to generate the same kind of profit than the video game shop: fast food require the staff to cook each dish for each customer which is wasting alot of time and requires a huge amount of temp staff to run.

Any tips ?

Comment: wouldn't this be realistic? a video game retailer probably would make more with less effort than a restaurant?

Comment: Well I am not questioning this, I only want tips to succeed at the game. To be frank if you wanted to be realistic, the shop would compete with an online shop such as Amazon and you would go bankrupt.